# New and disambiguated [fpm] tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-disambiguation

The `fpm` tag currently refers to:

> FastCGI Process Manager - an alternative PHP FastCGI implementation with some additional features (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fpm )

There is another tool called "fpm". It's a packaging assistant for creating and converting debs, rpms and other package formats:

> The goal of fpm is to make it easy and quick to build packages such as rpms, debs, OSX packages, etc. (from https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ )

Can we:

- retag "fpm" as "php-fpm"
- create a new tag "ruby-fpm"
- tag [How can I install fpm (packaging tool) with isolated dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762303) with "ruby-fpm"

Note: I'm not sure if this is the most accurate way to disambiguate these tools. The PHP tool is written in PHP for use with PHP, so that name makes sense. The packaging tool is written in Ruby but can be used with any source, not just Ruby packages. Is "fpm-package-builder" too long for a tag?

Comment: _Is "fpm-package-builder" too long for a tag?_ Tags [must be no longer than 35 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) so thats not to long. Further I would suggest different names than php/ruby-fpm if they are different things and not just the same thing for a different language.

Comment: @AndréKool that's a good point, they are completely different things